# Functional Analysis and Lie Algebras/Representation Theory

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, semisimple-lie-algebras

I know there are infinite dimensional lie algebras and functional analysis deals with infinite dimensional vector spaces.

But functional analysis also is covers operators and limit structures like metrics and inner products.

**Question**: Is there any application of functional analysis to the study of Lie Algebras (and perhaps representations of Lie algebras?

Comment: Yes, there are applications of functional analysis to representation theory. There is even a journal [Functional Analysis and Its Applications](https://www.springer.com/journal/10688), which mentions first the applications to representation theory.